# physics solar radiation- 'longwave' and 'shortwave'

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

So I am answering a question that says:

Hence explain why solar radiation is neglected in atmospheric “longwave” calculations and Earth radiation is neglected in atmospheric “shortwave” calculations.

for the question both λ values fall into shortwave radiation category  λ<(or equal) to 4um). I know that we say that as λ increases radiation from the earth increases while solar radiation increases.

why because of this is longwave radiation and shortwave radiation neglected?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for the Physics site?

Comment: I don't think this is a math question. You could try [earth science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=radiation+balance).